# cppunit export local variable

Tags: c++, unit-testing, cppunit

```
for (int i = 0; i < 50; ++i)
    {
        CPPUNIT_ASSERT(RtcTime_GetDayOfWeek(TimeC[i])==RtcTime_GetDayOfWeek(TimeC[i+1]));
    }
```

This test fall down. How i can export 'i' on which this test fall down?

now my output

```
1) test: testEq (F) line: 55 rtc_test.cxx
assertion failed
- Expression: RtcTime_GetDayOfWeek(TimeC[i])==RtcTime_GetDayOfWeek(TimeC[i+1])
```

i want something like that

```
1) test: testEq (F) line: 55 rtc_test.cxx
    assertion failed
    - Expression: RtcTime_GetDayOfWeek(TimeC[i])==RtcTime_GetDayOfWeek(TimeC[i+1])
i=49
```

Comment: Did you try looking at the documentation for CppUnit?

Comment: It took me much less than a minute to find [this](http://cppunit.sourceforge.net/doc/cvs/group___assertions.html#ga1).

Comment: yes it don't help me

Comment: So you can't do e.g. `CPPUNIT_ASSERT_MESSAGE("i = " + std::to_string(i), RtcTime_GetDayOfWeek(TimeC[i])==RtcTime_GetDayOfWeek(TimeC[i+1]));`?

Comment: Also, I surely hope that `TimeC` (whatever that is) have at least 51 elements. Otherwise you will go out of bounds which is not checked by the test. Going out of bounds leads to *undefined behavior* and could actually make the test *pass*.

Comment: ye it have 100 elements

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do something like this, which will print a message when CppUnit asserts.

```
for (int i = 0; i < 50; ++i)
{
    std::stringstream oss;
    oss << "testing RtcTime_GetDayOfWeek(TimeC[i]) where i=" << i << std::endl;
    CPPUNIT_ASSERT_MESSAGE(oss.str(),
              RtcTime_GetDayOfWeek(TimeC[i])==RtcTime_GetDayOfWeek(TimeC[i+1]));
}
```